# How to remove unncessary white space

Tags: html, css, parallax, removing-whitespace

I followed a tutorial for parallax scrolling with pure CSS (link: http://callmenick.com/post/simple-parallax-scrolling-effect) and it seems to be fully working after implementation. The problem is, there is a white space between my site header/nav and the body which I don't know how to remove.

The link is here; I put my site header background color to red to make it more visible: http://cindy-li.com/

Any ideas what could be causing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: wow thanks for the quick response everyone! that worked :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don't just link to a site if you have a question. The better way is to include a short example of the code you're having problems with. Links can change but if you include your code (as much as necessary but as short as possible) in your question, it might actually be helpful to other users. Questions that are likely to be not helpful to someone else *might* get closed.

Comment: happy to help - just make sure that whatever change you make to the css includes the h1's in the other sections as well and isn't limitedto the first on on the page.

Comment: @mmgross will keep that in mind, thank you.

Comment: @gavgrif got it, thanks a lot!

Comment: true @mmgross, but the only way that problem was solved as quick as it was was to see the page in situ and inspect the elements as they are in the page. Cindy wuld have had to include all code for the page and the css to allow us to see it.

Comment: @gavgrif No argument there. I just wanted to point that out for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its the `<h1>Serene<h1>` thats causing the issue - check your css for that

Answer (score 2):

It's the margin set on the `h1` tag containing the word "Serene" at the top of the page. You can either remove the margin from that tag, or set `overflow: hidden` on its parent and find another way to center the text.

Answer (score 1):

set `margin-top: 0;` on `<h1>Serene</h1>`